# Npm install failed with “EINVAL: invalid argument, chown”

Tags: java, angular, maven, npm

I am using [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) to run my Angular App within the Java project, the plugin entry looks like this :

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>

                <configuration>
                    <nodeVersion>v6.10.3</nodeVersion>
                    <npmVersion>5.0.0</npmVersion>
                    <workingDirectory>src/main/ngapp</workingDirectory>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>npm run build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>

                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

My `mvn clean package` commands work perfectly fine in my **local environment** but it fails on the server where my jenkins is configured with the following error message.

```
[ERROR] npm ERR! path /code/src/main/ngapp/node_modules/.staging/@ngtools/json-schema-5dca9490
[ERROR] npm ERR! code EINVAL
[ERROR] npm ERR! errno -22
[ERROR] npm ERR! syscall chown
[ERROR] npm ERR! EINVAL: invalid argument, chown '/code/src/main/ngapp/node_modules/.staging/@ngtools/json-schema-5dca9490'
```

**Note:** The same configuration worked fine till yesterday but start breaking since morning.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to latest node/npm.

You can try with below .. should be working.

```
<configuration>
       <nodeVersion>v11.12.0</nodeVersion>
       <npmVersion>6.7.0</npmVersion>
</configuration>
```